How to create XML RPC request using .NET Core 8
This request created using .NET Framework
but it did not work in .NET Core because it's not supported
public XmlRpcStruct GetOffers(string msisdn, string userName, string password)
    {
        XmlRpcStruct req = new XmlRpcStruct
        {
            { "originHostName", _originalHostName },
            { "originNodeType", _originalNodeType },
            {
                "originTimeStamp",
                DateTime.Now
            }
        };
        string origTransId = DateTime.Now.Millisecond + msisdn;
        req.Add("originTransactionID", origTransId);
        req.Add("subscriberNumber", msisdn);
        req.Add("subscriberNumberNAI", 2);
        req.Add("offerRequestedTypeFlag", "11111000");
        XmlRpcStruct resp = null;
        IGetOffers proxy =(IGetOffers)XmlRpcProxyGen.Create(typeof(IGetOffers));
        XmlRpcTracer trace = new XmlRpcTracer();
        trace.Attach(proxy);
        proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
        proxy.KeepAlive = true;
        proxy.PreAuthenticate = true;
        proxy.UserAgent = "send_request/4.4/1.0";
        proxy.Url = AirServerUrl;
        proxy.XmlEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        proxy.XmlRpcMethod = "GetOffers";
        return proxy.GetOffers(req);
    }

So I need a way to simulate this using .NET Core 8
This peace of code
IGetOffers proxy =(IGetOffers)XmlRpcProxyGen.Create(typeof(IGetOffers));

I got an error here when search on , that the reflection in .net framework different in reflection .net core `

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please share the exact error message you get. Also please read the [tour] and [ask].
